# How to divide with exponentiation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say I wanted to multiply but couldn't actually use the multiply operation. I could do this:

$$(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2 \implies ab = \frac{(a+b)^2 - a^2 - b^2}{2} $$

Now, logically it should be possible to reverse this process, I should be able to divide two numbers without using the division operation. But I have no clue how to do that. I actually need this for something very niche and also I think it's an interesting problem

EDIT: Okay, you're right I didn't include enough information.

1. Only operate on Natural numbers
2. Only use addition, subtraction, exponentiation, root (no logs, no mult/div)
3. As @WhatsUp put it nicely, the goal is to express the division function $N \times N \rightarrow N,(a,b) \mapsto a/b$ in terms of polynomials of a and b
4. Remainder can be discarded or kept

Comment: Doesnt every term in your equation use multiplication? How do you define exponentiation?

Comment: Exponentiation is usually defined in terms of multiplication; however, even if we assume we can exponentiate, add and subtract all without multiplication - division is really just multiplication (from a Group Theory perspective anyway). Maybe there is some way to define exponentiation in some other way and work backwards to get back multiplication - but for our human brains, defining multiplication is extremely natural. Maybe I'm wrong, but I can't imagine it's easy to define some system for exponentiation without multiplication in a simple way

Comment: You should specify what sort of operations you are allowed to use. If you can do everything except for multiplication/division, there is a multitude of solutions. For example, $\frac a b = e^{\log a-\log b}$. Otherwise, the question is ill-posed.

Comment: the illustration is how we recover a bilinear form (such as a vector inner product) from a quadratic form, when characteristic is not $2.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite all the close votes, I think this could be an interesting problem if some more details are given.

As @tomasz said in the comment, the important thing is what operations are allowed.

My interpretation: in a field $K$, one wants to express the division function $(\cdot, \cdot): K \times K^\times \rightarrow K, (a, b) \mapsto a/b$ in terms of polynomials of $a$ and $b$.

In an infinite field, one may argue that this is not possible: if $a/b = h(a, b)$ holds for some polynomial $h$ and all $a, b\in K\times K^\times$, then we would have $a = bh(a, b)$, and putting $a = 1$ gives $1 = bh(1, b)$ for all $b \in K^\times$.

This cannot happen, as the polynomial $bh(1, b) - 1$, viewed as polynomial of $b$, has non-zero constant term and hence is non-zero, so it can only have finitely many roots.

In a finite field, the solution is simple, as $b^{-1} = b^{q - 2}$, where $q$ is the cardinality of $K$.

Comment: Yes, your interpretation is correct, I should've worded my question more clearly. I just don't quite understand how you got the answer.  Why $1=bh(1,b)$ "cannot happen"? So what if $bh(1,b) - 1$ can only have finitely many roots?

Comment: The polynomial $bh(1,b)-1$ has only finitely many zeros, but $K^\times$ is an infinite set. Therefore there must be an element $b_0$ of $K^\times$ such that $b_0h(1,b_0)-1\neq 0$. This contradicts our hypothesis on $h$.

Comment: Ahh, I see. So if $h(a,b) = a/b ~ \forall  a,b \in K \times K$ then $bh(1,b) -1 = 0$ must be true for any $b \in K$, which it can't be. So this means that there is no polynomial that can express the division of any two numbers $a,b \in K \times K$. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that's the case when $K$ is infinite, e.g. $K = \Bbb Q$ or $\Bbb R$.